# can't close previous frame to see well new frame java

Tags: java, swing

I have a problem with frames. I think my problem is logic one. I open menu frame and then when I click add passenger the frame doesn't open wel. I still can see previous frame. I used ideas posted on this forum to change setVisisble to (false) and I thought I will see correctly other frame but it didn't work well.   Could you please give me some advice. Thank you

```
public class DriverProgram 
{ 
     public static void main (String [ ] argument) 
      { 
          Flight sw101 = new Flight(); 
          sw101.setVisible(true);
      } 
 } 

import corejava.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Flight extends JFrame
{
SeatingChart sc = new SeatingChart();
WaitingList wl = new WaitingList();
private String buttons[] = new String[5];
private final Font MENU_FONT = new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 20);
JButton b;
ActionListener listener1 = new MenuClickListener();
private JTextField input =null;  
private JTextField firstName;
private JTextField middleName;
private JTextField lastName; 
private final Font NEW_FONT = new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD + Font.ITALIC, 20);

public Flight()
{
    menu();
}

void menu( )
{ 
    uiFrameMenu();
    addPanelMenu();
}

void uiFrameMenu()
{
    setTitle( "MENU" );
    setSize( 400, 400 );
    setLocationRelativeTo( null );
    setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );   
}

void addPanelMenu()
{
    setLayout( new BorderLayout() ); 
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setLayout(new GridLayout (5,1));

    buttons[0] = "Add Passenger";
    buttons[1] = "Remove Passenger";
    buttons[2] = "Seating Chart";
    buttons[3] = "Waiting List";
    buttons[4] = "Exit";


    for( int i = 0; i < buttons.length ; i++ )
    {
        b = new JButton( buttons[i]);
        b.setText( buttons[i] );
        b.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
        b.setFont(MENU_FONT);
        b.addActionListener(listener1);
        panel.add(b);
    }

    getContentPane();
    panel.setBackground(Color.MAGENTA);
    add(panel,"Center");
}

class MenuClickListener implements ActionListener
{
    MenuClickListener() { }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent event ) 
    {   
        if ( event.getActionCommand().equals(buttons[0]))   
        { 
            addPassenger();
        }
        else if ( event.getActionCommand().equals(buttons[1]))  
        { 

        }
        setVisible(true);
             }
}



void addPassenger( )
{
    this.setEnabled(false);
    uiFrameData();
    setLayout( new BorderLayout() ); 
    JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
    panel1.setLayout( new GridLayout(3, 2) );
    JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();
    panel2.setLayout( new GridLayout(3, 1) );
    JLabel l1 = new JLabel("First Name");
    JLabel l2 = new JLabel("Middle Name");
    JLabel l3 = new JLabel("Last Name");
    firstName = new JTextField();
    middleName = new JTextField();
    lastName = new JTextField();
    panel1.add(l1);
    panel1.add(firstName);
    panel1.add(l2);
    panel1.add(middleName);
    panel1.add(l3);
    panel1.add(lastName);
    add(panel1);
}

void uiFrameData()
{
    setTitle( "FIRST, MIDDLE AND LAST NAME" );
    setSize( 400, 400 );
    //setLocationRelativeTo( null );
    setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );   
}
}
```

Comment: Please define and describe better "doesn't open *well*" and "it didn't work *well*".

Comment: Edit: I think I see your problem: you want to use a CardLayout.

Comment: doesn't open well" and "it didn't work well". It means that it opens first frame menu and then when I choose add passenger I still can see some part of the first frame and I don't see correctly second frame.

Comment: Again, look into using a CardLayout. The tutorial can be found [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html). This will allow you to create and swap several JPanels, perhaps named menuPanel, addPassengerPanel,, removePassengerPanel, seatingChartPanel, and waitingListPanel.

Comment: crosspost: [java-forums.org: cant-close-previous-frame-see-well-new-frame-java](http://www.java-forums.org/new-java/57046-cant-close-previous-frame-see-well-new-frame-java.html)

Comment: See also [Multiple frames: good or bad practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9554657/418556)

Answer (score 3):

Better apply [CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html), for this scenario, as already told to you. Here I had modified your code, you are setting the `Layout` on your `JFrame` everytime, since it's the same `Layout` you are setting, why not do that only once. Why do add extra code everytime for no reasons :-) , Do `revalidate()` and `repaint()` on your `JFrame` after making changes to the GUI on the fly, so that they can be reciprocated to the viewer. Here I had made some change to the code.

```
//import corejava.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class DriverProgram 
{ 
     public static void main (String [ ] argument) 
      { 
          SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
          {
                public void run()
                {
                    Flight sw101 = new Flight(); 
                    sw101.setVisible(true);
                }
          });
      } 
 }

class Flight extends JFrame
{
    //SeatingChart sc = new SeatingChart();
    //WaitingList wl = new WaitingList();
    private String buttons[] = new String[5];
    private final Font MENU_FONT = new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 20);
    JButton b;
    ActionListener listener1 = new MenuClickListener();
    private JPanel panel; // changed this to instance field so it can be accessed, at button click.
    private JTextField input =null;  
    private JTextField firstName;
    private JTextField middleName;
    private JTextField lastName; 
    private final Font NEW_FONT = new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD + Font.ITALIC, 20);

    public Flight()
    {
        menu();
    }

    void menu( )
    { 
        uiFrameMenu();
        addPanelMenu();
    }

    void uiFrameMenu()
    {
        setTitle( "MENU" );
        setSize( 400, 400 );
        setLocationRelativeTo( null );
        setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );   
    }

    void addPanelMenu()
    {
        setLayout( new BorderLayout() ); 
        panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new GridLayout (5,1));

        buttons[0] = "Add Passenger";
        buttons[1] = "Remove Passenger";
        buttons[2] = "Seating Chart";
        buttons[3] = "Waiting List";
        buttons[4] = "Exit";


        for( int i = 0; i < buttons.length ; i++ )
        {
            b = new JButton( buttons[i]);
            b.setText( buttons[i] );
            b.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
            b.setFont(MENU_FONT);
            b.addActionListener(listener1);
            panel.add(b);
        }

        getContentPane();
        panel.setBackground(Color.MAGENTA);
        add(panel,"Center");
    }

    class MenuClickListener implements ActionListener
    {
        MenuClickListener() { }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent event ) 
        {   
            if ( event.getActionCommand().equals(buttons[0]))   
            { 
                addPassenger();
            }
            else if ( event.getActionCommand().equals(buttons[1]))  
            { 

            }       
        }
    }



    void addPassenger( )
    {
        //this.setEnabled(false);
        remove(panel);
        uiFrameData();
        JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
        panel1.setLayout( new GridLayout(3, 2) );
        JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();
        panel2.setLayout( new GridLayout(3, 1) );
        JLabel l1 = new JLabel("First Name");
        JLabel l2 = new JLabel("Middle Name");
        JLabel l3 = new JLabel("Last Name");
        firstName = new JTextField();
        middleName = new JTextField();
        lastName = new JTextField();
        panel1.add(l1);
        panel1.add(firstName);
        panel1.add(l2);
        panel1.add(middleName);
        panel1.add(l3);
        panel1.add(lastName);
        add(panel1);

        revalidate(); // If your JDK is 1.7 else use getContentPane().revalidate(); for JDK 1.6 or below
        repaint();
    }

    void uiFrameData()
    {
        setTitle( "FIRST, MIDDLE AND LAST NAME" );
        setSize( 400, 400 ); 
    }
}
```